# Moving from DX:AX register to single 32-bit register

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I'm having a problem adding to a product of a 16-bit multiplication. I want to multiply a year (such as 2015) by 365. To do so I

```
mov dx, 0    ; to clear the register
mov ax, cx   ; cx holds the year such as 2015
mov dx, 365  ; to use as multiplier
mul dx       ; multiply dx by ax into dx:ax
```

After checking the registers, I am getting the correct solution but is there a way so that I can store this product into a single register? I want to add separate values to the product and so I would like to move this product into a single  32-bit register.

Answer (score 6):

The usual method is to use a 32 bit multiply to start with. It's especially easy if your factor is a constant:

```
movzx ecx, cx      ; zero extend to 32 bits
                   ; you can omit if it's already 32 bits
                   ; use movsx for signed
imul ecx, ecx, 365 ; 32 bit multiply, ecx = ecx * 365
```

You can of course also combine 16 bit registers, but that's not recommended. Here it is anyway:

```
shl edx, 16 ; move top 16 bits into place
mov dx, ax  ; move bottom 16 bits into place
```

(There are other possibilities too, obviously.)

Answer (score 3):

```
mov dx, 0    ; to clear the register
mov ax, cx   ; cx holds the year such as 2015
mov dx, 365  ; to use as multiplier
mul dx       ; multiply dx by ax into dx:ax
```

You can start by simplifying this code (You don't need to clear any register before doing the multiplication):

```
mov  ax, 365
mul  cx       ; result in dx:ax
```

Next to answer your title question and have the result DX:AX moved into a 32-bit register like EAX you could write:

```
push dx
push ax
pop  eax
```

Comment: 2x push word + pop dword is compact but quite bad for performance: causes a store-forwarding stall on modern CPUs, like 10 cycles extra latency on top of the normal store/reload, so about 15 cycles of latency.  (And on old CPUs without cache, like 80386, it's 3 memory accesses instead of just register operations.)